# Jquery Conflict with Venobox and calling function from outside global scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, lightbox

I try to load a div using venobox and inside this div I bound the element to click function as shown in fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/mosta/gm9yf6vm/

if you click on "Delete" it will show alert but after loading venobox it does not work

```
  $(".btnconfirmdelete").click(function (event) {
              alert('');

          });
```

Apreciate your help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

jQuery, **along with a number of other libraries**, using the '*$*' symbol as an **alias** for the actual object name - '*jQuery*'.

As multiple libraries may attempt to claim the same dollar alias, and have differing APIs, code expecting that the dollar sign is aliased to a specific library like yours may work inconsistently between pages depending on the libraries used - or not at all if conflicting libraries are globally used.

There are a number of ways you can deal with this-

1. Solely use the full jQuery object name in your code. The sample you provided would become-

   ```
   jQuery(".btnconfirmdelete").click(function (event) {
      alert('');
   });
   ```

   You can and probably should use [jQuery no conflict](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) to deregister the alias with jQuery to avoid fighting with the other library-

   ```
   jQuery.noConflict();
   ```
2. You can assign jQuery to **another alias** by assigning the result of the jQuery noConflict function to a variable.

   ```
   var foo = jQuery.noConflict();

   foo(".btnconfirmdelete").click(function (event) {
      alert('');
   });
   ```
3. You can alias jQuery back to the dollar sign within the scope of a Immediately Invoked Function Expression (remember variables in JavaScript have function rather than block scope). Again you'd want to use noConflict to avoid issues outside of the function.

   ```
   (function ($) {
       // Other code

       $(".btnconfirmdelete").click(function (event) {
           alert('');
       });

       // More code
   })(jQuery)
   ```

jQuery have an excellent help page which expands on this at http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

To complete *your specific* answer though, there was an error in your code - the function 'callme' was referenced two function scopes outside where it is defined.

I have [forked your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwdst/3g60s6pp/) and the corrected code is below. I've also improved your formatting which is good practice as it helps you visually understand the code heirachy to avoid issues like this-

```
 (function ($, Sys) {

    $(document).ready(
        function () {
            $('.venobox').venobox();

            /* custom settings */
            $('.venobox_custom').venobox({
                framewidth: '400px',        // default: ''
                frameheight: '300px',       // default: ''
                border: '10px',             // default: '0'
                bgcolor: '#5dff5e',         // default: '#fff'
                titleattr: 'data-title',    // default: 'title'
                numeratio: true,            // default: false
                infinigall: true            // default: false
            });

            $(".btnconfirmdelete").click(function (event) {
                alert('Delete');   
            });

          function callme () { 
              alert('Called');
          }

          callme();
    });
}(jQuery, window.Sys));
```

Comment: Thanks but I am afraid your fiddle is not working either, did you try click "Dialog" >> "Delete" 
it does not fire the alert